# Pandas DataFrame column (Series) has different index than the Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

Consider this small script:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})
b = df.a
b.index = b.index + 1
df['b'] = b
print(df)
print(df.a - df.b)
```

the output is:

```
   a    b
0  1  NaN
1  2  1.0
2  3  2.0

0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    NaN
```

while I was expecting `df.a - df.b` to be

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.0
```

How is this possible? Is it a Pandas bug?

Comment: Interestingly enough, `aa.index` and `aa.a.index` are different. Looks like pandas got confused by replacing indexes of the references (in `bb.index = bb.index + 1`).

Comment: Exactly. Is this intended behavior (can I find a place where this is documented?) or is it a bug?

Comment: To extend the comment from @YevhenKuzmovych, `aa.a.index` is different before and after the addition of column 'b'.  Having column 'a' be modified by adding an adjacent column seems like weird behavior to me too, though I think it may also be a case of pandas not being used as intended.  Perhaps OP should look into `.diff()` and `.join()` to avoid needing to assign new columns as whole `Series` objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
aa = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})
bb = aa.a
bb.index = bb.index + 1
aa['b'] = bb
aa.reset_index(drop=True)  # add this
```

your index does not match.

Comment: So, each Dataframe column remembers its own index and doesn't assume the Dataframe index? This is very counterintuitive to me

Answer (score 1):

When you do `aa.b - aa.a` , you're substracting 2 `pandas.Series` having a same lenght, but not the same index :

```
aa.a

1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Where as:

```
aa.b

0    NaN
1    1.0
2    2.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

And when you do :

```
print(aa.b - aa.a)
```

you're printing the merge of these 2 `pandas.Series` (regardless the operation type : addition or substraction), and that's why the indices `[0,1,2]` and `[1,2,3]` will merged to a new index from 0 to 3 : [0,1,2,3].

And for instance, if you shift of 2 your `bb.index` instead of 1:

```
bb.index = bb.index + 2
```

that time, you will have 5 rows in your new `pandas.Series` instead of 4. And so on..

```
bb.index = bb.index + 2
aa['b'] = bb
print(aa.a - aa.b)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get what you expect:

```
aa = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})
bb = aa.a.copy()
bb.index = bb.index + 1
aa['b'] = bb
print(aa)
print(aa.a - aa.b)
```